# How to list only N files in directory using java

Tags: java, java-io

If I have a directory contains a lot of files (about 1000 file). Some of these files named ***.processed*** and other not.

How can I list only 10 unprocessed files.

I am using this code to filter the processed file.

```
File[] inputFileList = inputDirectory.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                    return !pathname.getName().endsWith(".processed");
                }
            });
```

But if the number of un-processed files is huge, this may lead to memory error. so I need to read a limited number of files each time the application will run.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Which is why you should use java.nio.file. Using Java 8:

```
final Path baseDir = Paths.get("path/to/dir");

final List<Path> tenFirstEntries;

final BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> predicate = (path, attrs)
    -> attrs.isRegularFile() && path.getFileName().endsWith(".processed");

try (
    final Stream<Path> stream = Files.find(baseDir, 1, predicate);
) {
    tenFirstEntries = stream.limit(10L).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Using Java 7:

```
final Path baseDir = Paths.get("path/to/dir");

final List<Path> tenFirstEntries = new ArrayList<>(10);

final DirectoryStream.Filter<Path> filter = new DirectoryStream.Filter<Path>()
{
    @Override
    public boolean accept(final Path entry)
    {
        return entry.getFileName().endsWith(".processed")
            && Files.isRegularFile(entry);
    }
};

try (
    final DirectoryStream<Path> stream 
        = Files.newDirectoryStream(baseDir, filter);
) {
    final Iterator<Path> iterator = stream.iterator();
    for (int i = 0; iterator.hasNext() && i < 10; i++)
        tenFirstEntries.add(iterator.next());
}
```

Unlike `File.listFiles()`, java.nio.file use lazily populated streams of directory entries.

One more reason to ditch `File`. This is 2015 after all.

Comment: Pay attention that endsWith() for Path works not in same way as for String

Answer (score 4):

In Java 8, you can directly use `Files.walk()` to create a `Stream` of `Path`:

```
Path folder = Paths.get("...");
final int nbFilesToFound = 10;
List<Path> collect = Files.walk(folder)
                          .filter(p -> Files.isRegularFile(p) && !p.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".processed"))
                          .limit(nbFilesToFound)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In Java 7, you should not use `DirectoryStream.Filter` if you want that the files iteration stops as soon as the number of files to find is reached.
You could create a `SimpleFileVisitor` implementation to achieve it.

Whatever the number of files, to achieve such a requirement : extracting a specific number of files matching to a predicate from a directory, using `SimpleFileVisitor` appear straighter and more efficient than `DirectoryStream.Filter`.
So I think that it should be favored.
See my answer in [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48765712/how-to-get-specific-no-of-files-from-a-directory-using-java/48765832#48765832) to see how to implement it.

Comment: Does this limit loading of all the files into the memory and then do the filter?